# Extract Left Upper Triangular in R

Tags: r

I have the following matrix

`A = matrix(c(10,20,30,40,50,0,60,0,0),3,3,byrow=TRUE)`

My goal is with the use of a generic function to take the Left Upper Triangular, i.e. the result should be

`res = c(10,20,30,40,50,60)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is

```
a1 <- t(apply(A, 1, rev))
a1[upper.tri(a1, diag = TRUE)]
```

---

Or if the intention is to get rid of 0s

```
as.vector(na.omit(c(t(replace(A, A == 0, NA)))))
#[1] 10 20 30 40 50 60
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the particular order in ```res``` ?

Comment: @Jonathan1234 in `R`, it is the column order, so assuming that you want to remove the 0's, it is easier to replace the 0 with `NA`, transpose and remove the NA with `na.omit`

Answer (score -1):

A detour using the data frame format could look as follows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

A %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  stack() %>%
  group_by(ind) %>%
  slice(1:(n()+1-as.integer(str_sub(ind, -1)))) %>%
  pull(values)

# [1] 10 40 60 20 50 30
```